# Is it appropriate to ask for technology advice?

Tags: discussion, recommendation-questions

Is is appropriate to ask what to use to program something?

In my case, I want to build a simple web page (in Python/Django), where you could upload a list of CSVs and the result would be multiple graphs. I don't know what I should use and how to make the web page run offline to make it as much simple as it could be.

Is that a good question for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 15):

No.

Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Your question, as currently posed, is also Too Broad.  Taken to it's logical conclusion, "I have this [very specific list of requirements].  Given [my particular set of circumstances], which technology is best?"

To which the community would simply reply with "Use [My favorite technology]."  You would get a dozen different answers, none of them informative.

If you can make your question *that* specific, it might pass muster at Software Recommendations.  Read their Help Center first, before asking your question there.

Comment: So it's also Primarily Opinion-Based. Probably also a little unclear, and maybe even a duplicate of some other closed question.

Comment: What about asking "Does software library exist to X?"? Or if not that, then what about "Does software library exist to do X - but please under no circumstance recommend anything or tell me the name of that software?"?